# Error while using like statement in django raw sql

Tags: sql, django, sql-like

I have a raw sql query which is always giving error while executing. Here is my query

```
Users.objects.raw('select target, username from users where location like \'%s%%\' and date(modified) = \'2011-06-14\'',[location])
```

I am taking the `location = 'BUILD'`

Location values would be 'BUILD_A', 'BUILD_B','BUILD_C'.

When I am executing the raw sql, below is the error I am getting.

> DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>       that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>       'BUILD'%' and date(modified) = '2011-06-14'' at line 1")

In MySQL terms I need to execute the following query:

```
Select target, username from users where location like 'BUILD%' and target = '2011-06-14'
```

I have googled it but could not able to get it. Please some one help me

Answer (score 8):

I have solved my problem in this way.

`location = location + '%'`

`users_list = Users.objects.raw('select target, username from users where location like %s and date(modified) = %s',tuple([location,date]))`

The above statement executes perfectly without any error and I can able to render the results in template also.

Comment: Thank you, that's such a simple solution to make LIKE and ILIKE queries work in raw.

Answer (score -1):

Below query works for me,

query = "Select target, username from users where location like 'BUILD%'" 
results = Users.objects.raw(query)